# Undefined reference to log10 function

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I am building using Eclipse Kepler, and have included `math.h`. However, I am getting an error

> 'undefined reference to log10'.

Also types `uint8_t` and `unit32_t` are not being resolved. I have included both `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h`, just to be sure, but wasn't successful. Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 18):

> *'undefined reference to log10'.*

Because, the header file only provides the *forward declaration* of the function. The actual function definition is present in the ("math") library. You need to link with the math library using `-lm`.

Reference: [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/log10.3.html) for `log10`

Also, AFAIK, `uint<N>_t` are present in `<stdint.h>`. Please check for the existence for the header file itself and/or any typos (like `unit32_t` in your example) in your code.

Comment: 'undefined', rather than 'unresolved' sounds like a compiler error, rather than linker?