# Converting a string into an array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, linux, linker

Am trying to convert user's input of at least `17` characters into an array. Say for example the user's input is `25281582252`, by using `x = arr[1]` , `5` is assigned to variable `x`. 
I've not had success yet. I get a `"undefined reference to log10"` with `gcc` on linux. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int x;

    printf("enter x");
    scanf("%d",x);
    int numOfDigits = log10(x) + 1;
    char* arr = calloc(numOfDigits, sizeof(char));
    for(int i=0;i<numOfDigits;i++,x/=10){
        arr[i] = x % 10;
    }

    printf("first num: %d",arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to log10 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403210/undefined-reference-to-log10-function)

Comment: `scanf("%d",f);` where if `f` declared? And why not `char array[20] = "";` and then `scanf ("%16s, array);` and you will already have the input in an array? Or if you need an `int` array, just loop to gather input into an integer array.

Comment: I wasted few minutes trying to understand the irrelevant first part of the question.

Comment: @Stephen Docy, am not using eclipse

Comment: Meh, everybody starts somewhere. Some just start with a lot more confusion than others....

Comment: “scanf("%d",f);” really?

Comment: Please enable and fix all compiler warnings. Also `25281582252` won't fit a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a `"undefined reference to log10"`

You need to link your program with the math library using `-lm`.

But this is just a start. Fix the following issues:

a) allocate extra character for null string terminator if you want your string to be properly terminated.

b) `scanf("%d",x);` requires pointer to `x`

c) `int`  variable cannot store `17` numbers, use `long int`

d) you cannot store `int` into char `array`, your digit has to be converted to `ASCII` char.

f) your algorithm stores characters in a reverse order, you need to reverse your string

e) allocated memory has to be freed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void reverse_in_place(char * str, size_t len) {
   size_t i, j;
   for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j ; i++, j--) {
        char a = str[i];
        char z = str[j];
        str[i] = z;
        str[j] = a;
   }
}

int main(void){
    long int x;
    int i;

    printf("enter x:\n");
    scanf("%ld",&x);

    int numOfDigits = (int) (log10(x) + 1);

    printf("numOfDigits =  %d\n", numOfDigits);

    char* arr = calloc(numOfDigits + 1, 1);

       for(i=0; i < numOfDigits; i++){
            arr[i] = (char) ((x % 10) + '0');
            printf(" %c", arr[i]);
            x /= 10;
    }

    reverse_in_place(arr,strlen(arr));        
    printf("\nFirst num is: %c in string %s",arr[0], arr);

    free(arr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
enter x:                                                                                                                                    
451236789012345678                                                                                                                          
numOfDigits =  18                                                                                                                           
 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 3 2 1 5 4                                                                                                        
First num is: 4 in string 451236789012345678
```

Comment: Thanks sg7. You saved me

Comment: @alvo :) No problem. I am glad that I could help.